# Using JFileChooser to allow Swing user to specify output location

Tags: java, swing, java-8, filesystems, jfilechooser

I have to write a Java 8 Swing app and a part of the application generates an output file (Excel spreadsheet). So at some point in the UI, the user will have to:

1. Select a directory on their file system, where the Excel file will be written to; and then
2. Enter the name of the Excel file (if they specify ".xls" or ".xlsx" in the file name, the app will output/write the file in the respective XLS/XLSX output; if they omit the file extension the default will be XLSX)

I'm interested in what a decent UX solution here is, and how that maps to Swing controls and their layout.

I know I can use `JFileChooser` to choose a directory or a specific file, but I've never used it to select a directory **and** enter the name of a *new* (doesn't exist on the file system yet) file name + extension.

Any ideas as to what solution I can offer here that is functional, elegant and simple/easy to use & understand?

Comment: What specific challenge do expect when using a `JFileChooser` for selecting a new file? There’s a text field below the file list where you can enter a new name and it works like the file selection dialogs you can find in all other applications.

Comment: Thanks @Holger (+1)...I guess I'm still concerned about the file extension logic I mentioned above. If the user leverages this text field to specify a file name, they might: (**i**) omit an extension ("`some-spreadsheet`"), or they might (**ii**) provide an explicit extension ("`some-sheet.xls`" or "`some-sheet.xlsx`") or they might (**iii**) provide an "invalid" (not supported) explicit extension ("`some-sheet.fizzbuzz`"). In the first case I want to enforce a `.xlsx` extension. In the second case I will allow whichever they specific (XLS or XLSX). Third case is an error.

Comment: We have have 2019. A dot is not a special character anymore. If the user specifies `some-sheet.fizzbuzz`, just add the `.xlsx` extension, i.e. `some-sheet.fizzbuzz.xlsx`. So the logic is just, add the extension if not specified. I’d perform the logic after the dialog has been confirmed. The only thing to consider is that the user might not be aware if adding `.xlsx` makes the name matching an existing file, but I’d ask for overwrite confirmation anyway, if the result is matching an existing file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Apache's FileNameUtils, or implement you own extension extraction with String manipulation using substring and indexOf... I'll give you an example of first case.

After using a default JFileChooser as suggested, you can just check for specified file name, as JFileChooser will return a File object (or null if nothing is selected, so first check for null values):

```
JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
File selectedFile = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();

if (selectedFile != null) {

    String givenExtension = FilenameUtils.getExtension(selectedFile.getName());

    boolean noExtension = "".equals(givenExtension);
    boolean xlsx = givenExtension.toLowerCase().contains("xlsx");
    boolean xls = givenExtension.toLowerCase().contains("xls");

    String newFileName = selectedFile.getName();

    if (noExtension) {
        newFileName += ".xlsx";
    } else if (!xlsx && !xls) {
        throw new Exception("Invalid name");
    }
}
```

Remove *toLowerCase()* if you don't want different cases to be accepted.

This should do what you want ;)